# Open last modified file and copy in last modified workbook

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

I am trying to do the following: open the last modified saved XLS file (contains only 1 sheet) in a folder and copy it next to the last sheet of another last modified workbook which is saved in another folder.

Not sure is clear but happy to elaborate if needed. For the time being I am using the below code which surely needs enhancement.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Sub CopyMonthlyData()

Dim sFldr As String
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File
Dim fsoFldr As Scripting.Folder
Dim dtNew As Date, sNew As String
Dim sFileName As String

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

sFldr = "path"

Set fsoFldr = fso.GetFolder(sFldr)

For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
    If fsoFile.DateLastModified > dtNew Then
        sNew = fsoFile.Path
        sFileName = fsoFile.Name
        dtNew = fsoFile.DateLastModified
    End If
Next fsoFile

Workbooks.Open Filename:=sNew
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Sheets(1)
Windows(sFileName).Activate
ActiveWindow.Close
```

Comment: And what problem do you have? ?Should `Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")` be the last modified workbook of the other workbook?  If yes, do the same to identify it, but using another folder path. If not, why did you mention the second last modified workbook?

Comment: No Workbooks("Book2.xlsm") is the current workbooks I am using to run the macro. By doing the same to identify it it means that I should add a second search function? If yes where should I start? thanks

Comment: It it is obviously your current (open) workbook. But must it be the one you referenced as the other last modified workbook? Then, you do not have a function in your code, but you can make one able to retrieve the last modified file from a workbook, in both cases. I will show you how, if you confirm that this is the meaning of `Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")`.

Comment: My bad. This is indeed my current (open) workbook. Not the one I am looking to open is located in a different folder. I confirm that this is the meaning of Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")

Comment: OK. I will prepare a piece of code able to identify both last changed files from each folder and copy the first sheet of the first one before the first sheet of the second one. Is that a description matching your need?

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks a lot FaneDuru

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub CopyMonthlyData()
 Dim strWbCopy As Variant, strWbDest As Variant, wbCopy As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
 Dim strCopyFoldPath As String, strDestFoldPath As String
 strCopyFoldPath = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Tari" 'put here the fodler path for the file to be copied
 strDestFoldPath = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\PDA"  'folder path for the destination file

 strWbCopy = getLastModifFile(strCopyFoldPath)
 strWbDest = getLastModifFile(strDestFoldPath)

 Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=strWbCopy)
 Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=strWbDest)

 wbCopy.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=wbDest.Sheets(1)

 wbCopy.Close
End Sub

Function getLastModifFile(sFldr As String) As String
 Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
 Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File, fsoFldr As Scripting.folder
 Dim dtNew As Date, sNew As String, sFileName As String

 Set fsoFldr = fso.GetFolder(sFldr)

 For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
    If fsoFile.DateLastModified > dtNew Then
        sNew = fsoFile.path
        sFileName = fsoFile.Name
        dtNew = fsoFile.DateLastModified
    End If
 Next fsoFile
 getLastModifFile = sNew
End Function
```

You must only take care to change `strCopyFoldPath` and `strCopyFoldPath` with your appropriate paths. And be sure that all files in the two processed folders are .xls files... Otherwise, the function must also compare the file extensions.

The next function does not need any reference:

```
Function getLastModifFile(sFldr As String) As String
 Dim fso As Object, fsoFile As Object, fsoFldr As Object
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Dim dtNew As Date, sNew As String, sFileName As String

 Set fsoFldr = fso.GetFolder(sFldr)

 For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
    If fsoFile.DateLastModified > dtNew Then
        sNew = fsoFile.path
        sFileName = fsoFile.Name
        dtNew = fsoFile.DateLastModified
    End If
 Next fsoFile
 getLastModifFile = sNew
End Function
```

Comment: Great many thanks for your help. I tested it and I have a compile error (User-defined type not defined) pointing this part Scripting.FileSystemObject. I tried to activate the latest Microsoft Active X Object library but doesnt seem to solve the issue. Any clue?

Comment: @David Harry: Ups... Add, please, a reference to `'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'`. In VBE: `Tools ->References...` It can be done even without such a reference but the object must be firstly declared. But, I would like to sugest you to try adding the reference. It will be also useful in the future, I think...

Comment: I searched in the references menu and cannot find it (maybe linked to the fact that I am not the administrator, PC from work)...

Comment: @David Harry:  I do not think so... Do you see a lot of other references, but not the one in discussion? Or you cannot see anything in the References window?

Comment: @David Harry: I added a new function not needing any reference. Replace the first one with this one.

Comment: I see a lot of references but not this one in the discussion

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks again for all your help and time FaneDuru!

Comment: @David Harry: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that it works...